# Distance and absolute value differences?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My textbook: '.. the length of a vector is in many ways analogous to the absolute value of a real number.'

My question: How are the length of a vector and the absolute value of a real number  'analogous in many ways' and not simply equivalent?  In what ways are they different?

Comment: The absolute value of a number is a very special case of length of a vector, so has "additional" properties.

Answer (score 1):

Similar algebraic relationships hold: $|kx| = |k||x|$ where $k,x$ are numbers or $k$ is number and $x$ is a vector (these are analogous but not exactly the same, i.e. not equiv).  Also consider the triangle inequality: $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ where $x,y$ are number or $x$ and $y$ are vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the real line is a special kind of vector space, and absolute value measures vector length in that space. The only difference is that vector length is a more general notion: it applies also to vectors in higher dimensions.

(But generally, they are analogous in the sense that they both tell you the magnitude of the entity, but ignore its `direction': absolute value of a real number ignores the sign (whether it is pointing up or down, is it were). In the more general setting the length of a vector merely tells you its length but not the direction.)